# ipython3 does not work in the terminal with python3.7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-3.7

I recently upgraded from Python3.6 to Python3.7. Since I have upgraded, when I type in `ipython3` in the terminal I get an error:

```
~$ ipython3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 124, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Furthermore I have noticed that my jupyter-notebook does not seem to work with the python3 kernel now as well (I get the kernel dead error).

NOTEs:

- ipython and jupyter-notebook are working with fine when I use them with Python2.
- I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) although I don't think this is relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE** Please update your installed packages. 
This error for `pexpect` has been reported and closed already [issue](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/453)

---

In Python 3.7, `async` and `await` are now reserved keywords. This is what is breaking some of your installed packages.

If you do not need the new features in 3.7, roll back to 3.6 and wait until your packages are updated to support the new syntax in 3.7

[What's New in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

Comment: What packages does this refer to? Apologies, I'm not too knowledgeable about this stuff.

Comment: In your error code, near the end it says `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):` indicates that you have a package called `pexpect` that is using `async`. But in 3.7, async is now a reserved keyword just like `import` or `class` so it can no longer be used a variable name. ipython seems to be using this so uninstalling it might reveal some unintended consequences.

Answer (score 27):

`async` is a reserved keyword in python3.7 and an old version of pexpect is using `async` as variable. The solution is to upgrade pexpect.

For me, it was conflicting with apt-get installed python3, so I had to first uninstall it/them:

`sudo apt-get remove python-pexpect python3-pexpect`

And then

`sudo pip3.7  install --upgrade pexpect`

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I did not uninstall anything and simply did $pip3  install --upgrade pexpect I was running Python3.8 and jupyter would not launch again. pexpect was on verion 4.2.1 and it is now on version 4.8.0

Answer (score 2):

I just solve this problem by upgrading pexpect manually.

Download pexpect4.6 source code from https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/releases/tag/4.6

Extract the source code, get into the folder and install the pexpect by:

`sudo python3.7 setup.py install`

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, having the current version of the `pexpect` package should solve this. In my case, the `python3-pexpect` package that I had installed through apt was stuck on an old version and I first had to remove it. Then installing the current `pexpect` package through pip3 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`async` is a reserved word in `Python 3.7`

You can edit the packages yourself if you feel comfortable doing it. 
Here is a shell command that does just that:

```
sed "s/async/_async/g" "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py" > tmp.txt && cat tmp.txt > "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py" && rm tmp.txt
```

Otherwise, you might want to use Python 3.6 while waiting for an update.

Comment: `~$ pip3 uninstall pexpect` >>
`Cannot uninstall 'pexpect'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: You either have to get rid of it in some way or you must go back to 3.6. Editing code isn't hard if you really need 3.7

Comment: I don't think it is advisable to remove `pexpect` given that it is required by ipython3. And the OP wants ipython3 to work. Removing might just break it further.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue related to `async` being keyword in Python 3.7

As given [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/956#issuecomment-410432983), updating `pipenv` might be the solution

Comment: I'm not using a virtual environment. Either way I have upgraded pipenv but I am still getting the same error message