# I can't run ipython and when i try to run it i get syntax error

Tags: python, ipython

```
ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arvin/.local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/home/arvin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/arvin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/arvin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/arvin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 116, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/home/arvin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/home/arvin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/home/arvin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Add your code in here

Answer (score 0):

`async` is a python keyword used for coroutines, so you cannot use it normally like a variable. Try changing that line (which should be line 224 in your program) to

```py
def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async_=False):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i just type ipython command and the whole thing is given me by zorin terminal. i think maybe i should reinstall zorin os i may have done smth wrong while installing ipython

Comment: I don’t think anything is wrong with the platform you are using, although reinstalling might help

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after installing Python 3.8

```
$ ipython
[ . . . ]
def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Upgrading `pexpect` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56853127/2314737) solved the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pexpect python3-pexpect

sudo pip3 install --upgrade pexpect
```